# Flask Postgres client on Azure: No module named 'psycopg2' but it is installed

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, flask

I've build a Flask app that connects with Azure PostgreSQL database and uploads data from API to that database. Everything is working fine on my PC but when I open my webpage I get an error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Digging deeper I get:

```
StdErr: 
2017-05-30 16:15:48.465025: Unhandled exception in wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = handler()
  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 93, in get_venv_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))
  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 62, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "main.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\virtualenv_proxy.py", line 46, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

2017-05-30 16:15:48.480649: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 closed
```

When I used regular psycopg2 package I got error even during deployment on Azure. After changing my `requirements.txt` to this, deployment is successful, but the stated problem appears.

```
Flask==0.12.1
requests==2.17.3
git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34#egg=psycopg2
```

Deployment log:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling python deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'requirements.txt'
Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file.
Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
Detected python-3.4
Found compatible virtual environment.
Pip install requirements.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.12.1 in d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests==2.17.3 in d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 from git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34 in d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Cleaning up...
Overwriting web.config with web.3.4.config
        1 file(s) copied.
Finished successfully.
```

There is also top of my file `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import csv
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext
from datetime import datetime
import time
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

[...]
```

I tried to run command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34#egg=psycopg2
```

In my folder D:\Python34\Scripts> on Kudu but I get the following exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 370, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\\local\\Temp\\pip_build_RD00155D83D9EE$\\psycopg2\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-31a2b4dba04af9763e01b5b017870e20de3710c3.idx'
```

But it succeed in my `env` folder:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts>pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34#egg=psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 from git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py34 in d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical document about [`Troubleshooting - Package Installation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#troubleshooting---package-installation), it explained this case reason as below.

> Some packages may not install using pip when run on Azure. It may simply be that the package is not available on the Python Package Index. It could be that a compiler is required (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

So the solution to deal with this issue is shown the explaination of the document section.

1. Create a directory `wheelhouse` on your project.
2. Download the `psycopg` package wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg), and put it to `wheelhouse`.
3. Edit the `requirements.txt` file for the package as below, then re-deploy your project to Azure.

   ```
   --find-links wheelhouse
   psycopg2==2.7.1
   ```

Or you also can upload the wheel file to the path `wwwroot` of your webapp, and run the command `pip install psycopy2‑2.7.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl` via Kudu console `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.